# How extract Edition type ,Month and Year from this book price data set data in simple way?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-processing

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Edition_TypeDate': 
                [''2016'','5 Oct 2017','2017','2 Aug 2009','Illustrated, Import','Import, 22 Feb 2018','Import, 14 Dec 2017','Import, 1 Mar 2018','Abridged, Audiobook, Box set',
'International Edition, 26 Apr 2012','Import, 2018','Box set, 15 Jun 2014','Unabridged, 6 Jul 2007']})
```

[image]

I have one of the columns in my book dataset. Now From this column, I want three New columns.

1.Edition_Type -->that includes Import, Illustrated or null if nothing is mentioned

2.Edition_Month--->that includes Aug, Oct or null if nothing is mentioned

3.Edition _Year--->that includes 2016,2017,2018 or null if nothing is mentioned

How to do it? Help me to def a function that can I apply to this.

Comment: make your data frame clear and re post

Comment: copy and paste in jupyter notebook and run you get the clean output.I don't know how to get output here at stack overflow itself

Comment: @SahilKamboj - I think if added DataFrame sample in text then picture is no problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with keywords with `|` for regex `or`, for years `(\d{4}$)` means get 4digits numbers from end of string:

```
df['Edition_Type'] = df['Edition_TypeDate'].str.extract(r'(Import|Illustrated)')
df['Edition_Month'] = df['Edition_TypeDate'].str.extract(r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)')
df['Edition _Year'] = df['Edition_TypeDate'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}$)')
print (df)
                      Edition_TypeDate Edition_Type Edition_Month  \
0                                 2016          NaN           NaN   
1                           5 Oct 2017          NaN           Oct   
2                                 2017          NaN           NaN   
3                           2 Aug 2009          NaN           Aug   
4                  Illustrated, Import  Illustrated           NaN   
5                  Import, 22 Feb 2018       Import           Feb   
6                  Import, 14 Dec 2017       Import           Dec   
7                   Import, 1 Mar 2018       Import           Mar   
8         Abridged, Audiobook, Box set          NaN           NaN   
9   International Edition, 26 Apr 2012          NaN           Apr   
10                        Import, 2018       Import           NaN   
11                Box set, 15 Jun 2014          NaN           Jun   
12              Unabridged, 6 Jul 2007          NaN           Jul   

   Edition _Year  
0           2016  
1           2017  
2           2017  
3           2009  
4            NaN  
5           2018  
6           2017  
7           2018  
8            NaN  
9           2012  
10          2018  
11          2014
```

Comment: @SahilKamboj - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)